# Disintegration and Measure-zero sets

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose that $X,Y$ are Radon spaces, $\mu$ is a Borel probability measure on $X$, and $\nu$ is a $\sigma$-finite Borel measure on $Y$.  Fix some non-empty $A\subseteq X\times Y$ such that
$$
\mu\otimes \nu (A)=0.
$$
Can we then conclude (somehow by disintegration) that the projection of $A$ onto $Y$ are of $\nu$-measure $0$?

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  Let $X=Y=[0,1]$ and $\mu = \nu$ are both Lebesgue measure.  Then if $A$ is the diagonal, it has product measure 0 but its projection has measure 1.

Comment: @NateEldredge Interesting, would you happen to know of any "reasonable" assumptions which would make the conclusion true?

Comment: I think this and WollierThanThou's example indicate that it will basically never be true, except in very special cases.  For instance, $X$ cannot have any nontrivial null sets, which more or less rules out anything that isn't discrete.

Comment: It's also worth noting that by a similar construction, the projection of $A$ onto $Y$ need not even be measurable.

Comment: Question though, why do you say "projections", plural?

Comment: @NateEldredge True, I worked out the details and the construction can indeed be modified to give non-measurable outcomes; easily.  Also, (s) is a typo.  Thanks Nate!

Comment: Actually, in the case where $Y$ is finite and $\nu$ is the counting measure, the result seems to work.... am I wrong here?

Comment: No, WoolierThanThou's counterexample still works if $X$ has any nonempty null set.

Comment: True, thanks again Nate.

Comment: And saying that $X$ has no nonempty null sets is equivalent to requiring $X$ to be a countable set, in which every point has strictly positive measure.  In that case the result is easily seen to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $X$ is Hausdorff, then this statement is true for all $A$ if and only if one of the following holds:

- $X$ is countable, and the measure $\mu$ assigns positive measure to every point; or
- $\nu$ is the zero measure.

For one direction: suppose $X$ is countable, so $X = \{x_1, x_2, \dots\}$, and every point of $X$ has positive measure.  Then we can write $A = \bigcup_n \{x_n\} \times A_{x_n}$, where $A_{x} = \{y : (x,y) \in A\}$ is the section of $A$ through $x$.  By Fubini's theorem, $A_{x}$ is measurable for almost every $x$, which in this case means every $x$, and we have $0 = (\mu \otimes \nu)(A) = \sum_n \mu(\{x_n\}) \nu(A_{x_n})$.  This implies $\nu(A_{x_n}) =0$ for all $n$.  Now the projection $\pi(A)$ is given by $\bigcup_n A_{x_n}$ which is therefore measurable and has measure zero.

Of course if $\nu = 0$ then the result is trivially true.

For the converse: if $Y$ has a set of positive measure and $X$ has a nonempty set of zero measure, then as WoolierThanThou showed, the product of those sets  gives an $A$ for which the claim does not hold.  So either $Y$ has no sets of positive measure, which is to say $\nu =0$, or else the only measure-zero set of $X$ is empty.  Suppose the latter happens.  Since $X$ is Hausdorff, singletons are closed and thus measurable, so every singleton must have positive measure.  Then in order for $\mu$ to be finite or even $\sigma$-finite, there can only be countably many singletons, which is to say $X$ is countable.

Comment: I am going through the details and this has been an extremely helpful answer...Thank you Nate!

Answer (score 3):

Well, if $A=N\times B,$ where $N$ is a $\mu$-null set and $B$ is any Borel subset of $Y$, then $\mu\otimes \nu(A)=0,$ but the measure of $B$ can be whatever we want.